# Downloading large files in the background (Android )

Tags: android, file, background, download

What is the recommended solution for downloading large files in the background (larger than 100MB) on Android?

- DownloadManager
- Google Volley
- AsyncTask and HttpClient
- LargeFileDownloader

Comment: You can use an `IntentService` to perform download task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Intent Service / Service for long background operations as per your need and Google Volley is sufficient enough for your work as it handles all the network related tasks itself